# How did they know what a hypsilophodont mating call sounds like?

Tags: jurassic-park

On the tour of Jurassic Park, the guests are told that the hypsilophodonts will respond to a mating call.

> *“The main herd of animals can be found in the grassy plain below
>   you,” said the voice. “We can rouse them with a simple mating call.” A
>   loudspeaker by the fence gave a long nasal call, like the honking of
>   geese.*

The thing is, if they didn't breed any males, **how could they know what a mating call sounds like?**

Comment: You should probably clarify that you mean the book here.

Comment: Out-of-universe, we have an inkling of what some dinosaurs might have sounded like [by recreating their nasal cavities](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/how-parasaurolophus-set-the-mood-94657740/?no-ist).

Comment: They had the hypsilophodonts in the park, so they probably just recorded them

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because Jurassic Park (Isla Nublar) is a **theme park** in more ways than one. The true work of breeding and farming the dinosaurs is actually taking place on Isla Sorna in a hidden base known as "[Site B](http://jurassicpark.wikia.com/wiki/Isla_Sorna)".

In the sequel, "[The Lost World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_World_(Crichton_novel))" Ian Malcolm identifies that there are simply too many dinosaurs to have been bred in the miniature laboratories seen at Jurassic Park.

> Taken together, the whole complex had a utilitarian quality that
>   reminded Thorne of an industrial site, or a fabrication plant. He
>   frowned, trying to put it together. "Do you know what this is?" Thorne
>   said to Malcolm. "Yes," Malcolm said, nodding slowly. "It's what I
>   suspected for some time now." "Yes?" "It's a manufacturing plant,"
>   Malcolm said. "It's a kind of factory." "But it's huge," Thorne said.
>
> "You see," Malcolm said, "visitors to Hammond's park at Isla Nublar
>   were shown a very impressive genetics lab, with computers and gene
>   sequencers, and all sorts of facilities for hatching and growing young
>   dinosaurs. Visitors were told that the dinosaurs were created right
>   there at the park. And the laboratory tour was entirely convincing.
>
> ...
>
> "But actually, Hammond's tour skipped several steps in the process In
>   one room, he showed you dinosaur DNA being extracted. In the next
>   room, he showed you eggs about to hatch. It was very dramatic, but how
>   had he gotten from DNA to a viable embryo? You never saw that critical
>   step. It was just presented as having happened, between rooms.

Given that they were suffering high levels of unexplained deaths (and becoming increasingly desperate to improve mortality rate) the Site B staff released non-carnivorous dinosaurs from the factory bays.

The book explictly mentions that they were working with both male and female embryos so it's reasonably likely that the Site B scientists were allowing them to breed in mated pairs or flocks which explains how they'd know what the mating calls sound like.

---

Out of universe, the film's producers created the various mating calls and dinosaur noises using sounds from [real-life amphibians, mammals and birds](http://www.vulture.com/2013/04/how-the-dino-sounds-in-jurassic-park-were-made.html). It's at least possible that the Jurassic Park scientists used the same technique, mixing contemporary sounds and using trial and error until they found something that regularly attracted the female dinosaurs.

Comment: It says in canon that they allowed them to breed on this other island (your last sentence)?

Comment: @Scimonster - Kinda. They reference that blood samples are being taken from a "Gallimimus bullatus (Male)" embryo,  Then, in the next memo they talk about "having trouble keeping the newborn animals alive, so they tagged them and released them."